# Handling a license-like system with Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, licensing

I'm trying to come up with a way to handle licenses for a pet-project in Django. Say I wanted customers to have to pay for a license, and that allows them to access the website up until that license expires.

Are there built-in tools to handle something like this in Django?

Right now all I can think of is creating a new "license" model, with a foreign key to my customer model and a datetime field and then extending the customer model to check whether the license is still valid:

```
class License(models.Model): 
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
    license_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Then I would extend the customer model with this method:

```
def has_license(self, license):
    try:
        license = self.license.get(license=license)
    except Exception:
        return False

    return license.license_end > timezone.now()
```

And I suppose on each view that is restricted by a license I would have to check `if customer.has_license(license):` (passing their valid license object).

Though it would seem like I would be writing the same few lines over and over on each view that needs to be protected.

Would there be an easier way to set this up (or something like this)?

Though it's a bit relevant, I would also have to come up with a solution for license keys and authenticating those, that's an entirely new question so I won't include it on this question.

Comment: Hello Mormoran, Have you done this with your product?

Comment: I have implemented a similar solution to my question. I used the same code on the licence model, extending it with a has_licence() method. Then on a scheduled task, I check every 24 hours at midnight whether the customer's license is still valid. If the result is false, then I delete their session and log everyone out (customers have multiple users). Then I check their licence again on login (extended the user model). and If and their license is expired, I refuse the login and redirect to the license page where they can upload a new license file

Comment: If we deploy a product in enterprice level thats means we deploying souce code on his machine right. if anyone aware with python then he can easily remove has_licence()  check as per my understanding. Are you using any hiden secret key to decrpt licence key?

Comment: Well in my case the client does not have access to the source code, so I don't have to worry about them modifying the methods in the models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of middlewares

1. Create a middleware.py and below code

   ```
   class LicenceMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
           self.get_response = get_response
           # One-time configuration and initialization.


   def __call__(self, request):
       # Code to be executed for each request before
       # the view (and later middleware) are called.

       response = self.get_response(request)


       if check_date:
           return response
       else:
           return render(request, 'licence_expired.html')
   ```
2. Add your middleware to settings.py middleware section

Now for each request/response it checks the licencemiddleware and returns response.

You can create one more field in model to keep track the date.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion. I've used custom middleware on other parts of the site, and although I have already implemented a different solution, this one is very clean and concise. I'll accept it as the answer, thanks for taking the time to explain the code too.

Comment: Where does this ``check_date`` variable come from. I think it is not a good practice to render stuff or access model fields or other view functionalities in a middleware.